# Are there any extensions for either Boost.Test or cppUnit which could provide HTML outputs etc?

Tags: boost, gallio, cppunit

I am involved in development of unit level test cases for our project. There are both managed code and native C++ code. After some study I chose NUnit for managed code. I would either use Gallio or FireBenchmarks which is an extension to provide HTML outputs and charts etc.

Do we have extensions like this for cppUnit or Boost.Test ? I have not decided which one to use. If there are none, which of these would be easier to extend to enable such a plugin ?

Please give your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Boost.Test to generate XML output. The [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/log-xml-format.html) says:

> This log format is designed for
>   automated test results processing. The
>   test log output XML schema depends on
>   the active log level threshold.

This can be enabled by specifying `-output_format=XML` on the command line, or by setting the environment variable `BOOST_TEST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=XML`. The related docs are [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html).

It is also possible to configure Boost.Test at compile time to produce XML output by default (described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/log-ct-config.html))

In order to generate HTML you either need to implement your own formatter (which is possible, but nicely underdocumented, so please ask on the list) or to transform the XML in a postprocessing step.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, Rather than XML, we prefer HTML format. Do we have the xml->HTML formatter? Kindly help on that

Comment: I don't know of any xml-->html converters, but that doesn't mean there won't exist one. It shouldn't be too dificult to create a custom formatter for Boost.Test directly emitting html, though.